# Displaying Array Data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I new on laravel. So i tried to save this data to my Database and display it on my app. I managed to save it but i can't display the data.

```
{
  "2": {
    "name": "Ice Latte",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 20000
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "Ice Lemon Tea",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 20000
  },
  "6": {
    "name": "Ice Chocolate",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 20000
  }
}
```

So this is my full length data that i already get from my db.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Udin","data":{"2":{"name":"Kopi Creamy","quantity":1,"price":20000},"6":{"name":"Ice Chocolate","quantity":1,"price":20000},"3":{"name":"Es Teh Manis","quantity":1,"price":20000}},"isActive":0,"created_at":"2022-07-02T03:46:56.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-07-02T04:14:45.000000Z"}]
```

Here is my Order table migrations

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->default('guest');
            $table->json('data');
            $table->boolean('isActive')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here is my Order table model

```
protected $fillable = ['name','data','isActive'];

protected $casts = [
     'data' => 'array'
];
```

I've tried `{{ $order->data[0] }}` on my view. Where i tried to display the data.
but it said `undefined array key 0`.

So i check it with `{{print_r(array_keys($order->data))}}` and this is what it returns `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 [2] => 3 ) 1`

I want the data to be display like this

```
Ice Latte (2)
Ice Lemon Tea (1)
Ice Chocolate (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define index of $order as:

```
{{ $order[0]->data; }}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it returns Attempt to read property "data" on null

Answer (score 0):

use loop on your view.

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
  {{ $order->name }}
   ...
  // other order keys

@endforeach
```

Comment: So i tried to get all the data and return to view the structure. here what it returns
`[{"id":1,"name":"Udin","data":{"2":{"name":"Kopi Creamy","quantity":1,"price":20000},"6":{"name":"Ice Chocolate","quantity":1,"price":20000},"3":{"name":"Es Teh Manis","quantity":1,"price":20000}},"isActive":0,"created_at":"2022-07-02T03:46:56.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-07-02T04:14:45.000000Z"}]`

Comment: did i save the data on a wrong format??

Answer (score 0):

try array_values instead of array_keys as:

```
array_values($order->toArray());
```

or

```
array_values($order);
```

Comment: it returns `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Kopi Creamy [quantity] => 1 [price] => 20000 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Ice Chocolate [quantity] => 1 [price] => 20000 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Es Teh Manis [quantity] => 1 [price] => 20000 ) ) 1`

Comment: i tried to do `array_values($order->data)`

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer.

```
 @foreach($order['data'] as $d)
                  <p>{{ $d['name'] }} ({{ $d['quantity'] }})</p>
                @endforeach
```